# Does a CrudRepository delete also remove underlying large objects of Blob fields

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with a `@Lob` annotated `Blob` field:

```
@Entity
public class Entry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long tid;

    @Lob
    private Blob content;
}
```

The `content` is created using Hibernate's [LobCreator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/LobCreator.html) and the entity then saved using a JPA [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html):

```
public Entry save(Entry template, InputStream source) {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    content = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(source);
    template.setContent(content);
    return entryRepository.save(template);
}
```

When using PostgreSQL as the underlying database the `content` column for a given `Entry` will not contain the actual large object itself but an `oid` referencing it.

Assuming I am now using a `CrudRepository` to `delete` a given entity I am wondering if I can be sure that not only the row itself will be deleted but also the large object or if I am then left with an orphaned large object.

I can solve this problem using [PostgresSQL specific functionality](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/largeobject/LargeObjectManager.html) but would like to stick with the database agnostic Hibernate approach if possible at all.

Comment: Is the blob logically a part of that row?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FileData {

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "file_data")
    private Blob fileDataBlob;

    public void freeFileDataBlob() throws SQLException {
        if (this.fileDataBlob != null){
            this.fileDataBlob.truncate(0L);
            this.fileDataBlob.free();
            this.fileDataBlob = null;
            LOG.info("freeFileDataBlob() successful");
        }
    }

}
```